# DevExpress - Apply same Conditional Formatting for selected cells

Tags: c#, devexpress, report, reporting

Is there a way to apply the same Formatting Rule to multiple table cells (setting visible to false) without to specify specific field. Just somehow to Eval() value of current table cell and apply formatting accordingly. E.g. hide all numeric cells with zero value ([] == 0) on the report with just one rule :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution so far -

```
private const string ZeroValue = "0,00";

    public FISaldoAccountReport()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        RegisterEvents();
    }

    private void RegisterEvents()
    {
        positionAmountDebitCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        positionAmountCreditCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        positionSaldoCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;

        partnerAmountDebitCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        partnerAmountCreditCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        partnerSaldoCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;

        accountAmountDebitCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        accountAmountCreditCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        accountSaldoCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;

        accountSumCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;

        reportAmountDebitCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        reportAmountCreditCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
        reportSaldoCell.BeforePrint += NumCellBeforePrint;
    }

    private static void NumCellBeforePrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentCell = sender as XRTableCell;
        if (currentCell == null) return;

        currentCell.Visible = !currentCell.Text.Equals(ZeroValue);
    }
```

Comment: where did you put those code? In the designer.cs file?